# How to Do this List Comparison with Find?

Tags: find

I do and get a list of files where I would like to delete many duplicate backup files

```
find . -type f -name '._*'
```

I would like to find those files which have a corresponding filename

- `/home/masi/._test.tex` matches `/home/masi/test.tex`
- `/home/masi/math/lorem.png` matches `/home/masi/math/._lorem.png`

Pseudocode about files wanted to be saved `filename` which has corresponding `._filename` but also save `filename` without `._filename`

```
find . -type f -name '._*' -exec \ 
   find filenameWithoutDotUnderscore, if yes, print the filename
```

Pseudocode 2 clarification about files wanted to be removed = `._filename` if there is a corresponding `filename`

- If there is `filename` and `._filename` in the same directory, print `._filename` such that I can remove the duplicate = `._filename`.
- Exclude `filenamePart1_.filenamePart2`, `bok_3A.pdf`, ... in `._filename`.
- Do not remove `._filename` if there is no corresponding `filename` in the same directory.

### Reviewing Wildcard's command

I do `find . -type f -name '._*' -exec sh -c 'for a; do f="${a%/*}/${a##*/._}"; [ -e "$f" ] && printf "rm -- %s\n" "$a"; done' find-sh {} +` but it returns too many files. I think I need more `&&` conditions beside the existence check (`[ -e "$f" ]`). It would be great to get here some content comparison and lastly diff if suspicion of much difference.

Systems: Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian 8.25
Bash: 4.3.42
Find: 4.7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `find`, but to do it robustly you will need to embed a shell one-liner as well.  The proper way to do this is one of the following:

Stuff the looping into the spawned shell:

```
find . -type f -name '._*' -exec sh -c 'for a in "$@"; do f="${a%/*}/${a##*/._}"; [ -e "$f" ] && printf %s\\n "$f"; done' find-sh {} +
```

Or, spawn a separate shell for each file to be tested (less efficient, potentially more readable):

```
find . -type f -name '._*' -exec sh -c 'f="${1%/*}/${1##*/._}"; [ -e "$f" ] && printf %s\\n "$f"' find-sh {} \;
```

---

To directly remove the backup files, change this to the following **for a dry run:**

```
find . -type f -name '._*' -exec sh -c 'for a; do f="${a%/*}/${a##*/._}"; [ -e "$f" ] && printf "rm -- %s\n" "$a"; done' find-sh {} +
```

Then **once you're satisfied** with the list of commands that gets printed, use:

```
find . -type f -name '._*' -exec sh -c 'for a; do f="${a%/*}/${a##*/._}"; [ -e "$f" ] && rm -- "$a"; done' find-sh {} +
```

---

Notes:

In all of these, the `find-sh` argument is an arbitrary string; you could put anything there.  It gets set as `$0` within the spawned shell and is used for error reporting.

`for a in "$@"; do` is exactly equivalent to `for a; do`.

[`printf` is better than `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943).

[Quoting is important](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943).

Comment: @Masi, the first two commands find the files whose names start in `._` and if there is a file in the same directory *without* the `._`, print *that* file's name.  They are system independent.

Comment: `${a%/*}` expands to the value of the variable `a` with the *last* slash and everything after it removed; `${a##*/._}` expands to the value of the variable `a` with everything up to the last occurrence of `/._` removed.  The `/` in between is a literal slash.  See `LESS='+/Parameter Expansion' man bash`.

Comment: @Masi, do you want to remove the `._filename` files or the `filename` files?  I've bolded the relevant lines of my answer; I already included a "dry run" version....

Comment: @Masi, [dry run definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=dry+run+definition).  I already provided that.

Comment: @Masi, `[ -e "$f" ]` *is* an existence check.  Make a backup first.  (You should have backups anyway.)  Use the command in subdirectories first.  Delete them manually, if you like.  But your original exact question has been exactly answered.  Certainly you should study up enough to understand what the command is doing before you blindly run it, but have you even *attempted* to understand what the command I posted does?

Comment: Yes, I have. I think the existence check verifies that `filename` exists. However, I think it is not enough. I think other `&&` conditions are required. What do you think?

Comment: @Masi, I don't know your requirements.  If you want to find files with matching names (your question), I've answered it.  If you want to [find files by duplicate contents](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71176/135943), there are already answers for that.  Please reread your question, and then see if my answer answers your question; if so you should accept it.  If you have other peculiarities not described in your question, you should ask a new question rather than editing this one in a way that invalidates the answers given.