# How to remove duplicated directories that contain the same files?

Tags: directory, rm, diff, duplicate

I have multiple directories that contain text files. Some of these directories are named differently yet contain the same text files. How do I remove all duplicated directories?

Comment: There are a few questions here about locating and removing duplicate files. One is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71176/find-duplicate-files (about finding, but `fdupes` can also remove, I believe).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ rmlint --types duplicatedirs <path>
```

That will list duplicate dirs and create a shell script (rmlint.sh) that you can optionally run to delete them.

See [the user guide](http://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for installation instructions etc.