# Output lines with the same md5 sum

Tags: find, uniq

I have a script like this

```
find path -type f -exec md5sum {} +'
```

It has this conclusion

```
/tmp
❯ find $pwd -type f -exec md5sum {} + 

\a7c8252355166214d1f6cd47db917226  ./guess.bash
e1c06d85ae7b8b032bef47e42e4c08f9  ./qprint.bash
8d672b7885d649cb76c17142ee219181  ./uniq.bash
2d547f5b610ad3307fd6f466a74a03d4  ./qpe
523166a51f0afbc89c5615ae78b3d9b0  ./Makefile
57a01f2032cef6492fc77d140b320a32  ./my.c
c5c7b1345f1bcb57f6cf646b3ad0869e  ./my.h
6014bc12ebc66fcac6460d634ec2a508  ./my.exe
0ff50f0e65b0d0a5e1a9b68075b297b8  ./levik/2.txt
5f0650b247a646355dfec2d2610a960c  ./levik/1.txt
5f0650b247a646355dfec2d2610a960c  ./levik/3.txt
```

We need such a conclusion

```
5f0650b247a646355dfec2d2610a960c  ./levik/1.txt
5f0650b247a646355dfec2d2610a960c  ./levik/3.txt
```

Comment: This looks like a classic [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You're obscuring your actual problem (finding duplicates) by asking about a problem you've encountered with your solution. Unless you're looking for MD5 collisions between different files for some reason?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you’ve got GNU `uniq`, you can ask it to show all lines duplicating the first 32 characters¹:

```
find path -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort | uniq -D -w32
```

The list needs to be sorted since `uniq` only spots consecutive duplicates. This also assumes that none of the file paths contain a newline character; to handle that, assuming GNU implementations of all the tools, use:

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum -z {} + | sort -z | uniq -z -D -w32 | tr '\0' '\n'
```

(GNU `md5sum` has [its own way of handling special characters in file names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/424628/86440), but this produces output which isn’t usable with `uniq` in the way shown above.)

---

<sup>¹ Technically, in current versions of GNU `uniq`, it's the first 32 *bytes* that are considered, for instance UTF-8 encoded `á` and `é` characters would be considered identical by `uniq -w1` as their encoding both start with the 0xc3 byte. In the case of 0-9a-f characters found in hex-encoded MD5 sums though, that makes no difference as those characters are always encoded on one byte.</sup>

Answer (score 15):

If your task is to find duplicate files, you could also use `fdupes`:

> Searches  the  given  path for duplicate files. Such files are found by comparing file sizes and MD5 signatures,  followed  by  a  byte-by-byte comparison.

```
fdupes -r .
```