# Given a filepath, how do I find every copy of that file?

Tags: files, search

I know of programs such as `rdfind` or `fdupes`. They solve a similar but more complicated problem.

Given a file path and a directory, I want to search that directory recursively for every copy of that file - be it under other name, permissions or ownership.

If for instance I did `rdfind needle.file haystack/`, it would also find files other than `needle.file` that are duplicated only within `haystack`.

I could filter the output of `rdfind`, but if `haystack/` is large, this will do a lot of unnecessary work.

Should have a command line application, since I intend to use it in a script/cron-job.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/709531/is-there-a-tool-or-script-that-can-very-quickly-find-duplicates-by-only-comparin/) to a similar question can help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

A simple approach:

- Get the `md5sum` of your target file, store it in a variable
- Get the size of your file, store in a variable
- Use `find` to run `md5sum` on all same-sized files
- `grep` the output of `find` for our target MD5 hash

```
target_hash=$(md5sum needle.file | awk '{ print $1 }')
target_size=$(du -b needle.file | awk '{ print $1 }')
find haystack/ -type f -size "$target_size"c -exec md5sum {} \; | grep $target_hash
```

Comment: Without testing it in detail, it looks fine to me. One could probably extend it a bit and write a full shell script that finds duplicates this way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Czkawka ([Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.qarmin.czkawka) and [GitHub](https://github.com/qarmin/czkawka)).

It's a nice GUI-tool with advanced features such as checksum etc.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but it seems there's no way to do that with Czkawka, it has the same "problem" as in my `rdfind` example.

Answer (score 1):

If number of files is not big - less than 1000 for example, bash script can be suitable. Otherwise, execution of binaries (`md5sum`, `stat`) in loop will create noticeable overhead.

File sizes matters, because if we have 1000 files with 1G size, then binaries loading overhead can be neglected as relatively small. But if we have 1000 000 files with size 1K, then another story.

#### Variant №1

`md5sum` usage.

**find_dups_by_md5.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

get_size() {
    stat -c"%s" "$1"
}

get_hash() {
    md5sum "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1 
}

needle=$1
needle_size=$(get_size "$needle")
needle_hash=$(get_hash "$needle")

shopt -s globstar
GLOBIGNORE=$needle

for f in **; do
    cur_file_size=$(get_size "$f")
    if [[ "$needle_size" != "$cur_file_size" ]]; then
        continue
    fi  

    cur_file_hash=$(get_hash "$f")
    if [[ "$needle_hash" != "$cur_file_hash" ]]; then
        continue
    fi  

    echo -e "duplicate:\t${f}"
done
```

#### Variant №2

`cmp` usage.

Simple byte by byte comparison even better - less code, same result and even a little faster. Hash calculation is redundant here, because this hash is used once. For each file we make hash by `md5sum` (needle file included) and `md5sum` processes whole files by definition. Thus, if we have for example 100 1 Gygabyte files, `md5sum` will process all 100G, even if these files are different at first Kilobyte.

So, in case of single comparison each file with target, byte by byte comparison time will be the same in worst case (all files have same content) or faster if files have different content (assuming that md5 hash calculation time equals byte by byte comparison).

**find_dups_by_cmp.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

get_size() {
    stat -c"%s" "$1"
}

needle=$1
needle_size=$(get_size "$needle")

shopt -s globstar
GLOBIGNORE=$needle

for f in **; do
    cur_file_size=$(get_size "$f")
    if [[ "$needle_size" != "$cur_file_size" ]]; then
        continue
    fi  

    if ! cmp -s "$needle" "$f"; then
        continue
    fi  

    echo -e "duplicate:\t${f}"
done
```

**Testing**

Test files generation

```
###Generate test files
echo_random_bytes () {
    openssl rand -base64 100000;
}

shopt -s globstar

mkdir -p {a..d}/{e..g}/{m..o}

#Fill directories by some files with random content
touch {a..d}/{e..g}/{m..o}/file_{1..5}.txt
for f in **; do
    [ -f "$f" ] && echo_random_bytes > "$f"
done

#Creation of duplicates
same_string=$(echo_random_bytes)

touch {a..d}/{e..g}/m/dup_file.txt
for f in {a..d}/{e..g}/m/dup_file.txt; do
    echo "$same_string" > "$f"
done

#Target file creation
echo "$same_string" > needle_file.txt
```

Search of duplicates

```
$ ./find_dups_by_md5.sh needle_file.txt
duplicate:  a/e/m/dup_file.txt
duplicate:  a/f/m/dup_file.txt
duplicate:  a/g/m/dup_file.txt
duplicate:  b/e/m/dup_file.txt
duplicate:  b/f/m/dup_file.txt
duplicate:  b/g/m/dup_file.txt
duplicate:  c/e/m/dup_file.txt
duplicate:  c/f/m/dup_file.txt
duplicate:  c/g/m/dup_file.txt
duplicate:  d/e/m/dup_file.txt
duplicate:  d/f/m/dup_file.txt
duplicate:  d/g/m/dup_file.txt
```

Performance comparison

```
$ time ./find_dups_by_md5.sh needle_file.txt > /dev/null

real    0m0,761s
user    0m0,809s
sys 0m0,169s

$ time ./find_dups_by_cmp.sh needle_file.txt > /dev/null

real    0m0,645s
user    0m0,526s
sys 0m0,162s
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Panki's answer, this should have fewer invocations of `md5sum`,  which would improve performance if thousands of files are to be checked.

```
target_hash="$(md5sum needle.file | awk '{ print $1 }')"
target_size="$(du -b needle.file | awk '{ print $1 }')"
find haystack/ -type f -size "$target_size"c -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | grep "^$target_hash"
```

Caveat: As with the original, there may be display issues if file names contain new line characters.